# Mongo lookup in another document with either document doesn't exists or exists on a particular status

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have 2 collections

```js
Coll_1 : {
board_id
}

Coll_2 : {
board_id,
influencer_id,
status
}
```

We want to fetch all the `Coll_1` documents where
Either `Coll_2` does not contain `board_id` (common key in 2 tables)
Or `Coll_2` contains `board_id` with status `0`

Can anybody help in creating this query

I tried the lookup condition this way

```js
Coll_1.aggregate([{
      $lookup : {
        "from" : "Coll_2",
        "localField" : "board_id",
        "foreignField" : "board_id",
        "as" : "Coll_2"
      }
    },
    {
      "$match" : {
        $or : [
         {"Coll_2.influencer_id" : {$ne : influencer_id}},
           {
            "Coll_2.influencer_id" : influencer_id,
            "Coll_2.status" :  0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
])
```

Comment: `"Coll_2"` will be an array after the `"$lookup"` stage.  Is it possible that `"Coll_2"` will contain more than one member?  Your query indicates that `"influencer_id"` is part of the `"$match"` logic.  Is that correct?  If so, would you edit your question and describe that?